# Efficient extraction of patch features over an image

Tags: python, performance, image, matrix, numpy

*Input*:

- **data** - a matrix of size n*m*3*3 (complex values)
- **indices** - a list of coordinates (x,y), where x < n and  y < m
- **fp** - a feature parameter which is a tuple of ((fp11, fp12), (fp21, fp22)), id)
- **reference** - a list of  3*3 matrices
- **swrd** - a function which computes a similarity value between two complex valued 3*3 matrices

*Output*:

- **feature_values** - a list of features - one feature for each index in (indices)

*Functionality*:

Given an image (data) were each pixel is a 3*3 matrix. And there is a list of target pixels (indices). For each target pixel, I want to extract features of the patch surrounding it.

A patch feature is either:
a) the swrd of a pixel in the patch with a reference matrix or
b) the swrd of two pixels in the patch

Thus a feature can be described by the relative coordinates fp11, fp12 (x and y offset of pixel of interest 1) and fp21, fp22 (x and y offset of pixel of interest 2). 
If fp11 == fp21 and fp12== fp22, then i want to compute a), else i want to compute b). 
The reference matrix of interest is defined by the feature parameter called id.

Note that the indices of interest are already filtered so that the sum x+fp__ < n and y+fp__< m for all possible fp__.

*Code*

Computing the symetric revised wishart distance with regularization in case a matrix A or B is not invertible

```
def srwd(A, B):
    """This function computes the symetric revised wishart distance as from the paper
    SPECTRAL CLUSTERING OF POLARIMETRIC SAR DATA WITH WISHART-DERIVED DISTANCE MEASURES"""
    try:
        dist = 0.5 * np.trace(np.dot(A, inv(B)) + np.dot(B, inv(A))) - len(A)      
    except:
        A, B = A.reshape(3, 3) + np.eye(3) * 0.000001, B.reshape(3, 3) + np.eye(3) * 0.000001
        dist = 0.5 * np.trace(np.dot(A, inv(B)) + np.dot(B, inv(A))) - len(A)      
    return abs(dist)
```

Getting the features with the input as given above:

```
def feature(data, indices, fp, reference):
    # fp is a tuple of 2 coordinates in a patch ((x1,x2),(y1,y2),ref),
    # where ref is an index of a random reference matrix in reference only relevant in case x1=y1 and x2=y2
    res = []
    if fp[0] != fp[1]:
        for i in indices:
            x, y = i
            res.append(srwd(data[x + fp[0][0]][y + fp[0][1]], data[x + fp[1][0]][y + fp[1][1]]))
    else:
        for i in indices:
            x, y = i
            res.append(srwd(data[x + fp[0][0]][y + fp[0][1]], reference[fp[2]]))
    return res
```

Finally there is another loop such as:

```
for fp in feature_params:
    feature_values = feature(data, indices, fp, reference)
    #here work on feature_values
```

The current implementation is rather inefficent and a bottleneck of the whole process. How could I improve it?

Is there a chance to efficiently compute a feature matrix efficiently and operate on it afterwards?

An executable toy example including the whole code is given here (allowing copy-paste)

```
import numpy as np
from numpy.linalg import inv

#toy example
data = np.random.rand(1000, 1000, 3, 3) #an image of 1000*1000 pixels, each pixel a 3*3 matrix
indices = np.random.randint(3,96, size = (10000,2)) # a list of 10000 target pixels (lets assume they are unique)
reference = [np.random.rand(3,3)] # a single reference matrix in a list (in actual application there are multiple reference matrices)
feature_params = [((0,0),(-1,-1), 0), ((0,0), (0,0), 0), ((0,1), (0,0), 0), ((1,0), (0,0), 0), ((1,1), (0,0), 0)] 



def srwd(A, B):
    """This function computes the symetric revised wishart distance as from the paper
    SPECTRAL CLUSTERING OF POLARIMETRIC SAR DATA WITH WISHART-DERIVED DISTANCE MEASURES"""
    try:
        dist = 0.5 * np.trace(np.dot(A, inv(B)) + np.dot(B, inv(A))) - len(A)      
    except:
        A, B = A.reshape(3, 3) + np.eye(3) * 0.000001, B.reshape(3, 3) + np.eye(3) * 0.000001
        dist = 0.5 * np.trace(np.dot(A, inv(B)) + np.dot(B, inv(A))) - len(A)      
    return abs(dist)


def feature(data, indices, fp, reference):
    # fp is a tuple of 2 coordinates in a patch ((x1,x2),(y1,y2),ref),
    # where ref is an index of a random reference matrix in reference only relevant in case x1=y1 and x2=y2
    res = []
    if fp[0] != fp[1]:
        for i in indices:
            x, y = i
            res.append(srwd(data[x + fp[0][0]][y + fp[0][1]], data[x + fp[1][0]][y + fp[1][1]]))
    else:
        for i in indices:
            x, y = i
            res.append(srwd(data[x + fp[0][0]][y + fp[0][1]], reference[fp[2]]))
    return res

for fp in feature_params:
    feature_values = feature(data, indices, fp, reference)        
    #here work on feature_values
```

A final note about the dimensions of the actual problem:

- Image of size 6000*1700,
- around 500 features in feature_params
- indices is list of around 8.000.000 target indices

Comment: If there is any information that could improve the chance of a good answer, please make a request and i will further explain.

Comment: What exception is caught on srwd try-catch block/what causes an exception there? It might not be pythonic, but checking where to go before calculating might save some time over fail&catch

Comment: In case one of the two matrics (A or B) is not invertible, the inv() function returns an error. Regularization is therefore only used if exception is triggered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know enough matrix math to be able to help with those bits, but if `indices` is large, you can get at least a small speedup by deconstructing `fp` into individual local variables.

```
def feature(data, indices, fp, reference):
    # fp is a tuple of 2 coordinates in a patch ((x1,x2),(y1,y2),ref),
    # where ref is an index of a random reference matrix in reference only relevant in case x1=y1 and x2=y2
    ((x1, x2), (y1, y2), ref) = fp
    res = []
    if fp[0] != fp[1]:
        for i in indices:
            x, y = i
            res.append(srwd(data[x + x1][y + x2], data[x + y1][y + y2]))
    else:
        for i in indices:
            x, y = i
            res.append(srwd(data[x + x1][y + x2], reference[ref]))
    return res
```

It reads a bit cleaner, but it also runs faster because indexing into lists is (a hair) slower than accessing a local variable.  But 'a hair' times 8x10^9 is likely measurable.

Comment: Although a tiny improvement regarding performance, it is an improvement and increases readability. Therefore I consider this a valid answer and reward the bounty.